# Webpack proxy messing up my routing?

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, vue.js

So I'm using webpack for a project on 8080 with a backend on 3000. The proxy seems to work fine, as I can send requests to the backend and access it without issue. However. I need to include this middleware that allows me to have a user load the page, and if they've logged in within a certain amount of time, the initial request they send to the server logs them in automatically.

```
router.use(function (req, res, next) {
 //check token for routes beneath vvvv
})
router.post('/preauth', function (req, res) {
 //return user account info if req.token is valid
})
```

When I try to get to prauth, or even any route before that from the page loaded on 8080 I only touch the middleware and nothing else.

When I do npm run build then try it again from the identical page on 3000, it works as expected.

No, CORS is not enabled and the proxy does not rewrite any url.

Does anyone know if something in my Webpack config might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

You need install Cors in nodejs:npm install cors, you can try the following below or you see: [Nodejs + Vuejs](https://hoanguyenit.com/create-form-register-using-nodejs-vuejs.html)

```html
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()
 
app.use(cors())
 
app.get('/products/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'})
})
 
app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('This is a CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80')
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this was the answer. I tried setting cors through the chrome plugin and through Node and neither fixed the routing problem. Why was the request being diverted only to the middleware?